# Encountering an issue while attempting to fetch data from an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, axios

Here i am trying get a data from the url using axios. I am getting a data when i console log response.data
this is the log i get but when i try console log response.data.trees then it shows undefined. How can i solve this issue.

```
Fetch1 {
  "trees": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bao",
      "species_name": "Adansonia",
      "image": {
        "src": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia.jpg",
        "alt": "A large African baobab tree."
       }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Red Mangrove",
      "species_name": "Rhizophora mangle",
      "image": {
        "src": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia.jpg",
        "alt": "A free-standing red mangrove tree.",
      }
    }
  ]
}

Fetch2 undefined
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('url');
        setTrees(response.data.trees);
        console.log('Fetch1',response.data)
        console.log('Fetch2',response.data.trees)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The response you are receiving from the API is in JSON format. It is not an object. In order for you use it like an object like you expect, use `let data = JSON.parse(response.data)` and then do `data.trees` to access the element you want.

You can read more about JSON.parse() [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Hope this helps!

Comment: i get this error i do that 
Error fetching data: SyntaxError: Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position 691 (line 19 column 7)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at fetchData

Comment: Can you validate your API response? Check if the response returned is serialized properly as JSON or not. If the JSON string is valid, parse should work as expected.

Comment: Yes, the data is properly serialized as JSON. It follows the JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) format, with key-value pairs, arrays, and nested objects. Each property is enclosed in double quotes, and the structure is well-formed, making it valid JSON data.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the JSON snippet here for line 19 as the error states?

Comment: {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Red Mangrove",
      "species_name": "Rhizophora mangle",
      "image": {
        "src": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/16/Red_mangrove-everglades_natl_park.jpg",
        "alt": "A free-standing red mangrove tree growing in shallow water in the backcountry of the Cape Sable area of Everglades National Park.",
      }
    },

Comment: Please remove the comma at the end of the "alt": "A free-standing red mangrove tree growing in shallow water in the backcountry of the Cape Sable area of Everglades National Park.",  as it is not required in the JSON structure. This is the issue that prevents the parse.

Comment: is this because of the , in the end of the alt object?

Comment: Yes. Comma at the end violates the JSON structure.

Comment: Thank you. that helps. Do you know how can i remove it from the public API?

Comment: Validate this by copying the JSON from the response and do the change and see if the parse is happening. If that is the case, contact the team  of the API or raise an issue if possible.